# cordova, where is build.gradle file

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

Changing the `build.gradle`

and then I run `cordova build android` the `build.gradle` file is updated.

How can I change the dependencies of cordova / plugins?  Or force to a particular version?
Having issues with : google-gcm services

I am having conflicting dependencies of plugin causing the services to fail to build.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```